# Use wit.ai in a simple web chat

Tags: wit.ai

I have this scenario that I want to achieve;
On my web page I want to create a chat bot widget that helps my customers in the purchase process.

I have been looking into wit.ai and it seems like a perfect fit. However it seems like this only can be used within a Facebook messenger client, and not as a standalone chat widget on a web page.

Is this correct? If someone have made a web chat using wit.ai please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect it to just about anything. I built a chat bot with Wit.ai last year that used Kik app for the chat client.

In your case you might want to look at Api.ai. It was bought buy Google recently and has a built in webpage widget.